# Yii framework: Creating CActiveDataProvider with details from two tables

Tags: php, yii

I have database relation as follows between ***question table*** and ***Hardware detail table***.
*Question* and *HardwareDetail* has many to many relation. and *tbl_quesionhardwaredetial* table holds another new property called *answer*

I want to create active data provider (CActiveDataProvider) with list of questions and relevant answers for a given hardware detail.

I have pull relevant questions for a given hardware detail using following criteria.

```
$quesionsDataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Question', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'with'=>array('hardwaredetails'=>array( 
                        'on'=>'hardwaredetail_Id=' .$modelHD->Id, 
                        'together'=>true,
                        'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN', 
                )),
            ),
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>10,
            ),
        ));
```

But how can i attach the answer to the list of questions retrieved.

Thanks in advance for any help

. [image]

Comment: That diagram doesn't fit with your description of the relations

Comment: why, it explain correctly many to many relation between tbl_question and tbl_hardwaredetail. and table which hold many to many relation is tbl_quetionhardwaredetial. it has added field called answer

Comment: question and hardwaredetail don't have a direct relation

Comment: yes it is because it is many to many relation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating CActiveDataProvider you can create CSqlDataProvider which is more flexible and you can write sql queries by hand

Example:

```
$dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($qry, array(
                'keyField' => 'id',
                'totalItemCount' => $count,
                'sort' => array(
                    'attributes' => array('field1','field2')
                ),
                'pagination' => array(
                    'pageSize' => 5
                )
                    )
    );
```

$qry = your sql query for selecting records

$count = no of records(you should modify above $qry to find record count)

'keyField'= you should mention keyField, if you use different primary key field other than 'id'

further reading [CSqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to attach the answer to the question all you have to do is this:

```
$quesionsDataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Question', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'with'=>array('answers', 'hardwaredetails'=>array(  //  etc...
```

So just add the name of the relation of the Question model with the Answer model.